# IFormFile always return null in asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Here's how I upload file my Api action :

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<BaseListResponse<MediaStorageModel>> MediaBrand(IFormFile file, int brandId) 
{
    var files = new List<IFormFile>();
    files.Add(file);

    var response = await this.Upload(files, "brand", brandId);

    return response;
}
```

---

My Postman Configuration :

[image: postman_config]

I Upgraded my api from .NET Core 2.0 to 2.1 and my code is not working

Can anyone help about this ?

Comment: Is your controller decorated with the `[ApiController]` attribute? That attribute, among other things, switches the default binding source from `FromForm` to `FromBody`, so if you need to actually accept `multipart/form-data` or `x-www-urleconded` request bodies, you need to add `[FromForm]` to the param.

Comment: Even when adding FromForm attribute to the model parameter, I still get a null value for my IFileInfo, while I can see the file in the Request.Form.Files list...

Comment: None of them worked for me. I just tried `[FromForm(Name = "")] IFormFile file` attribute and it worked for me.

Answer (score 32):

I've faced the same issue, I was able to fix it by applying the 'Name' named parameter to FromForm attribute with name of the File field in the form. It specifies which field in the form to bind to the method parameter. Change your method signature as shown here.

```
[HttpPost("status")]
public async Task<BaseListResponse<MediaStorageModel>> MediaBrand([FromForm(Name ="file")] IFormFile file, int brandId)
```

Answer (score 21):

Make sure the form is the correct enctype

```
<form asp-action="Edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I also had to change how the Model bind works from the generated code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([Bind("Text,Example")] Example example)
```

to this code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Example example)
```

Answer (score 13):

In your form use

```cs
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Bingo.  Form needed to look like this:  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="input" action="[controller stuff]" method="post">

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Adding (Name = "body") to the from form worked for me

**Server Call**:

```
[HttpPost]
  [Route("UploadImage")]

public IActionResult UploadImage([FromForm(Name = "body")]IFormFile formData)
```

**Client code**:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('body', event.target.files[0]);

const config = {
  headers: {
  'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
}

axios.post(ApiURL,formData, config);
```

Comment: Basically, name is optional. FromForm expects payload in FromData from client, then you can read files. Also you can get Request.Form object instance.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it works as follows in net core

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ReadFormFile([FromForm]IFormFile miCsv)
{


}
```

**Request body:** Use as **key** the same name as the parameter

[image]

**Request Header:** Use as **Content-Type:** *multipart/form-data; boundary=xxxxxxxxxxx*
the boundary can be any value

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`IFormFile` could be `null` if app is hosted by Kestrel server and file size exceeds 28.6MB. To see if that's the case, check `HttpContext.Request.Form` property value.

Permitted file size can be adjusted by configuring `MaxRequestBodySize` Kestrel server option.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to make it work:

> Use `HttpPut` instead of `HttPost` on the controller action.

I was also surprised by this behavior. If someone can explain why it fixes the issue, it would help me.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method argument to take below model and add [FromForm], it should work.

```
public class FileUploadViewModel
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
}

public async Task<BaseListResponse<MediaStorageModel>> MediaBrand([FromForm] FileUploadViewModel viewModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<BaseListResponse<MediaStorageModel>> MediaBrand([FromQuery] int brandId, IFormFile file)
{
    var files = new List<IFormFile>();
    files.Add(file);

    var response = await this.Upload(files, "brand", brandId);

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update [FromForm] attribute, and don't put parameter into Headers, and put name of key is file and brandId.

I tested, It is Ok
[image: Add [FromForm] attribute]

[image: Only form-data and key is correct]

Answer (score 0):

If you use javascript and FormData object you need set the name of each file to 'files'

```
this.files.forEach((f) => {
         formData.append("files", f, `${this.path}/${f.name}`);
      });
```

if you use other name in your post you need to set it in the attribute of the post method

```
formData.append("someName", f, `${this.path}/${f.name}`);

 public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm(Name ="someName")] List<IFormFile> files)
```

Dont forget to set content-type

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had an angular 6 app using a custom HttpInterceptor which adds content-type of "application/json" to every Http request along with a token before sending to an api. 
Something like below. Remove the line with 'Content-Type': `application/json`. Without that none of the solution here works. .Net Core is smarter now to translate whatever object u are sending to the api so far it matches the model u create for the object in angular.

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class JwtHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      let clone: HttpRequest<any>;
      if (token) {
        clone = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Accept: `application/json`,
            'Content-Type': `application/json`,
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        });
```