# Why file IFormFile = null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

```
[Route("api/file")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Consumes("application/json", "application/json-patch+json", "multipart/form-data")]
[ApiController]
public class FileController : ControllerBase
{
    public FileController()
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostProfilePicture([FromQuery]IFormFile file)
    {
        var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
        var name = file.FileName;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Postman

[image]

Debug

[image]

In the end file = null
How to solve this problem?

Comment: I faced a similar issue, I've posted my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54285576/1343192

Answer (score 2):

You are sending it as `x-www-form-urlencoded`. You have to send it as `multipart/form-data`. File uploads only possible in this mode, hence also `IFormFile` will be `null` on all other modes.

`x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default mode and only use for sending key/vale encoded pairs within the request body.

Also `[FromQuery]` isn't necessary, because you can't upload files via query parameters.

Comment: The remove the `[FromQuery]` part since its not part of the query (query is the part of the url after the question mark `?key=value&key2=value2`)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're getting null from `IFormFile` because you specify required attributes for this operation on the Controller class, not on the controller method. Updating your code as below will solve the problem.

```
[Route("api/file")]
[ApiController]
public class FileController : ControllerBase
{

    public FileController()
    {

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostProfilePicture([FromForm]IFormFile file)
    {
        var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
        var name = file.FileName;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change attribute which selects source from which model binder will resolve `IFormFile` instance. Instead of `[FromQuery]` to `[FromForm]`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostProfilePicture([FromForm]IFormFile file)
```

Comment: also file = null. if attribute -> [FromForm]

Comment: @АндрейЛяшенко What `Content-Type` header you are sending (check Headers tab in postman), it should be `multipart/form-data`

Comment: I get content-type →text/html; charset=utf-8 . How can i get multipart/form-data?