# How can .NET Core's IFormFile recognise a .csv file?

Tags: csv, post, .net-core, postman, iformfile

I'm trying to post a .csv file using Postman, but when I debug it always has a null value.

I checked the csv file and it should be valid, I can open it both with Microsoft Office and Open Office.

I sent it both as `form-data` and as a `binary` in Postman, but neither worked.

I tried adding a `[FromForm]` attribute, like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54570203/1984657

I also tried as IFormFileCollection, but this didn't work either.

Below is the stripped down code, even here it still receives a null value

```
namespace csvApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CsvController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Post(IFormFile csv)
        {
            return Ok(csv);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when instead of passing it as parameter to my Post method, I'm getting it from `Request.Form.Files`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post()
{
    var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
    return Ok(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to "[Match name attribute value to parameter name of POST method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#match-name-attribute-value-to-parameter-name-of-post-method)"? i.e., something like this?

[image]

According to Microsoft documentation, "[Binding matches form files by name. For example, the HTML name value in  must match the C# parameter/property bound (FormFile). For more information, see the Match name attribute value to parameter name of POST method section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1)."